# Work with Strings, Java, Diacritic Method

Tags: java, string, diacritics

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                String input = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println(input);
                String[] sentences = input.split("\\. ");
                char[] reversedText = input.toCharArray();
                char[] normalizedText = input.toCharArray();
                int sentenceCount = 0;
                int vowelCount = 0;
                int consonantCount = 0;
                for (String sentence : sentences) {
                    vowelCount = 0;
                    consonantCount = 0;
                    sentenceCount++;
                    System.out.println(sentence);
                    String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
                    System.out.println("Number of words is " + words.length);
                    String lowerCase = sentence.toLowerCase();
                    char[] chars = lowerCase.toCharArray();
                    System.out.println("Number of characters is " + sentence.length());
                    for (char c : chars) {
                        if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u' || c == 'y') {
                            vowelCount++;
                        } else if (c == 'h' || c == 'k' || c == 'r' || c == 'd' || c == 't' || c == 'n') {
                            consonantCount++;
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("Number of vowels is " + vowelCount);
                    System.out.println("Number of consonants is " + consonantCount);
                }
                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.println("Number of sentences is " + sentenceCount);
                for (int i = (reversedText.length) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    System.out.print(reversedText[i]);
                }
                System.out.println(" ");
                char[] diacritics = {'ě', 'š', 'č', 'ř', 'ž', 'ý', 'á', 'í', 'é', 'ú', 'ů', 'Ě', 'Š', 'Č', 'Ř', 'Ž', 'Ý', 'Á', 'Í', 'É', 'Ú', 'Ů' };
                char[] normal = {'e', 's', 'c', 'r', 'z', 'y', 'a', 'i', 'e', 'u', 'u', 'E', 'S', 'C', 'R', 'Z', 'Y', 'A', 'I', 'E', 'U', 'U' };
                for (int i = 0; i < normalizedText.length; i++) {
                    char c = normalizedText[i];
                    int index = -1;
                    for (int j = 0; j < diacritics.length; j++) {
                        if (c == diacritics[j]) {
                            index = j;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (index != -1) {
                        normalizedText[i] = normal[index];
                    }
                }

                System.out.println(normalizedText);

            }}
```

I was working with Strings.
Can someone show me how to do this with a method? Also please point out things that are wrong with my code in general.

I was trying to replace all of the diacritics, with "normal" text, this is what I came up with, but it´s not a method but done manually.

Comment: Nice work! The code works, that's most important. The `public static void main(String[] args)` already is a method. But you can just rename it to whatever you want, remove the argument, and you'll have your method. It would probably be best as `public static String removeDiacritics(String textWithDiacritics)` that takes the input string as a parameter and returns the text without diacritics instead of printing it out. Then you can use that from your main method.

Comment: Just a comment on "normal" letters-  that isn't really how things work in all languages.  In some, they think of the letter with the diacritics as a different letter.  For example, ü in some languages is not a u with an attachment, they are different letters and the speakers do not think of the two as being related in any way.

Comment: Does this link help? https://www.baeldung.com/java-remove-accents-from-text. It uses `java.text.Normalizer` to split the composed characters and then removes the attached accents.

Answer (score 0):

There's still more to do, but the below code could give you a basic idea on how to create various methods.

I separated two methods out of the original code. You could improve it still, first and foremost go ahead and create a `private static void printReversed()` method to contain the reverse-text printing code. Next, slightly more advanced and more involved would be making all the methods return something instead of directly printing out stuff (like `removeDiacritics()` does). In programming we generally frown upon methods with "side-effects" (like printing) and prefer pure methods that take something in, transform it and return something back, so that the calling code can do whatever it wants with it. Like printing :).

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(input);
        System.out.println();

        printStatistics(input);

        char[] reversedText = input.toCharArray();
        for (int i = (reversedText.length) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.print(reversedText[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();

        String normalized = removeDiacritics(input);
        System.out.println(normalized);
    }

    private static void printStatistics(String input) {
        String[] sentences = input.split("\\. ");

        int sentenceCount = 0;
        int vowelCount = 0;
        int consonantCount = 0;
        for (String sentence : sentences) {
            vowelCount = 0;
            consonantCount = 0;
            sentenceCount++;
            System.out.println(sentence);
            String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
            System.out.println("Number of words is " + words.length);
            String lowerCase = sentence.toLowerCase();
            char[] chars = lowerCase.toCharArray();
            System.out.println("Number of characters is " + sentence.length());
            for (char c : chars) {
                if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u' || c == 'y') {
                    vowelCount++;
                } else if (c == 'h' || c == 'k' || c == 'r' || c == 'd' || c == 't' || c == 'n') {
                    consonantCount++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Number of vowels is " + vowelCount);
            System.out.println("Number of consonants is " + consonantCount);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Number of sentences is " + sentenceCount);
        System.out.println();
    }

    private static String removeDiacritics(String textWithDiacritics) {
        char[] normalizedText = textWithDiacritics.toCharArray();
        char[] diacritics = { 'ě', 'š', 'č', 'ř', 'ž', 'ý', 'á', 'í', 'é', 'ú', 'ů', 'Ě', 'Š', 'Č', 'Ř', 'Ž', 'Ý', 'Á', 'Í', 'É', 'Ú', 'Ů' };
        char[] normal = { 'e', 's', 'c', 'r', 'z', 'y', 'a', 'i', 'e', 'u', 'u', 'E', 'S', 'C', 'R', 'Z', 'Y', 'A', 'I', 'E', 'U', 'U' };
        for (int i = 0; i < normalizedText.length; i++) {
            char c = normalizedText[i];
            int index = -1;
            for (int j = 0; j < diacritics.length; j++) {
                if (c == diacritics[j]) {
                    index = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (index != -1) {
                normalizedText[i] = normal[index];
            }
        }

        return String.valueOf(normalizedText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace all the diacritics with normal characters, you'll need a way to map one character to another.
It appears you have this already, 2 separate arrays, where the index indicates the relationship.

I was able to produce valid results with the following method.

```java
String replace(String string) {
    char[] diacritics = { 'ě', 'š', 'č', 'ř', 'ž', 'ý', 'á', 'í', 'é', 'ú', 'ů', 'Ě', 'Š', 'Č', 'Ř', 'Ž', 'Ý', 'Á', 'Í', 'É', 'Ú', 'Ů' };
    char[] normal = { 'e', 's', 'c', 'r', 'z', 'y', 'a', 'i', 'e', 'u', 'u', 'E', 'S', 'C', 'R', 'Z', 'Y', 'A', 'I', 'E', 'U', 'U' };
    int index = 0;
    for (char character : diacritics)
        string = string.replace(character, normal[index++]);
    return string;
}
```

Example output

```
exposé = expose
lamé = lame
maté = mate
rosé = rose
résumé = resume
```

I reviewed your code, and made a few changes as recommendations.
You can replace the vowel and consonant counting procedures with regular expression pattern matching.

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println(input);
String[] sentences = input.split("\\. ");
char[] reversedText = input.toCharArray();
char[] normalizedText;
int sentenceCount = 0, vowelCount, consonantCount;
for (String sentence : sentences) {
    vowelCount = consonantCount = 0;
    sentenceCount++;
    System.out.println(sentence);
    String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
    System.out.println("Number of words is " + words.length);
    String lowerCase = sentence.toLowerCase();
    char[] chars = lowerCase.toCharArray();
    System.out.println("Number of characters is " + sentence.length());
    for (char c : chars) {
        if (String.valueOf(c).matches("[aeiouy]")) vowelCount++;
        else if (String.valueOf(c).matches("[hkrdtn]")) consonantCount++;
    }
    System.out.println("Number of vowels is " + vowelCount);
    System.out.println("Number of consonants is " + consonantCount);
}
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println("Number of sentences is " + sentenceCount);
for (int i = (reversedText.length) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    System.out.print(reversedText[i]);
System.out.println(" ");
normalizedText = replace(input).toCharArray();
System.out.println(normalizedText);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your code to break out each operation into its own, unit-testable and well named, method:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(input);
        String[] sentences = input.split(" ?\\. ?");
        for (String sentence : sentences) {
            System.out.println("Number of words is " + countWords(sentence));
            System.out.println("Number of characters is " + sentence.length());
            System.out.println("Reversed is " + new StringBuilder(sentence).reverse());
            System.out.println("Diacritics removed is " + removeDiacritics(sentence));
            System.out.println("Number of vowels is " + countVowels(sentence));
            System.out.println("Number of consonants is " + countConsonants(sentence));
        }
    }

    private static final Map<String, String> DIACRITIC_MAPPINGS = new HashMap<>() {{
        put("ě", "e");
        put("š", "s");
        put("č", "c");
        put("ř", "r");
        put("ž", "z");
        put("ý", "y");
        put("á", "a");
        put("í", "i");
        put("é", "e");
        put("ú", "u");
        put("ů", "u");
        put("Ě", "E");
        put("Š", "S");
        put("Č", "C");
        put("Ř", "R");
        put("Ž", "Z");
        put("Ý", "Y");
        put("Á", "A");
        put("Í", "I");
        put("É", "E");
        put("Ú", "U");
        put("Ů", "U");
    }};

    private static final Pattern DIACRITICS = Pattern.compile('[' + String.join("", DIACRITIC_MAPPINGS.keySet()) + ']');

    public static int countWords(String str) {
        return str.trim().split(" +").length;
    }

    public static int countVowels(String str) {
        return str.replaceAll("(?i)[^aeiou]", "").length();
    }

    public static int countConsonants(String str) {
        return str.replaceAll("(?i)[ .aeiou]", "").length();
    }

    public static String removeDiacritics(String str) {
        return DIACRITICS.matcher(str).replaceAll(mr -> DIACRITIC_MAPPINGS.get(mr.group()));
    }
}
```